# How to get just the error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
$('div#create_result').text(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
```

where the content of `XMLHttpRequest` is

```
responseText: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"error" : "User sdf doesn't exist"}
status: 200
statusText: parsererror
```

The result I see is

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 {"error" : "User sdf doesn't exist"}
```

where I would have liked

```
User sdf doesn't exist
```

How do I get just that?

Comment: If you are using jQuery anyway, why not use its [built-in Ajax library](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and [JSON shorthand method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

Comment: I have no idea how to get started on that. Can you give an example related to my code?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Check out the examples on getJSON linked above. A very primitive example would be `$.getJSON('your/url/here', function(data) { $('#create_result').text(data.error);});`

Comment: @Pekka put that in an answer so we can vote on it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use a regular expresion to extract value; something like:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(": \"(.+)\"}");
var str = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 {"error" : "User sdf doesn\'t exist"}';
var match = pattern.exec(str);    
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regular expression for this. jQuery's built-in Ajax engine brings along everything that is needed to parse the JSON properly.

The most primitive example looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('your/url/here', function(data) 
  { $('#create_result').text(data.error);}
);
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)